# Ubuntu software center android sdk install location

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-mate, android-sdk

I installed the android sdk platform tools from the ubuntu software center.

Where does it put the files?  For example, where would I find the location of tools such as "adb" and "fastboot"?

Comment: Why do you need to know where those are?

Comment: I am not on Ubuntu right now so I can't check but to guess, here: `/usr/local/bin/`, you could also try searching for them with something like `whereis -b adb` or `whereis -b fastboot` the -b searchs for binaries.

Comment: Ask the packaging system: `dpkg -L <packagename>`

Comment: Thanks. Both worked. But the dpkg option is what I wanted.  It installs to usr/bin.